# Powershell slowness in "get-childitem . -directory -recurse" when there are lots of files

Tags: powershell

I run:

```
PS F:\> gci F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound -r -directory | %{ $_.fullname }
```

and it shows:

```
F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2020-02-03
F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2020-02-04
...
F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2022-05-09
F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2022-05-10
```

then it "hangs" there.

Then I run the following command in another windows trying to find what is going on:

```
PS F:\> C:\temp\handle64.exe -p 3204
```

and I found:

```
  ACC: File  (RWD)   F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2020-04-28
  ...
  F08: File  (RWD)   F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound\2020-04-28
```

and the directory keep changing, so So it traverse each directory tring to find sub-directories, there are none but lots of files.

It took hours to complete the process. Never thought of the process would be so slow. It looks like it going through each file and test if it is a directory. Is there a quicker way to do this? I am using powershell 5.0 on Windows 2012R2.

Comment: yup, `get-childitem` is pretty slow.. are you interested in finding __only directories__ in `F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound`? and, are you only interested in the absolute path of the directories or are you looking from other information aside from the path?

Comment: I am finding ALL the empty directories older than X days to delete.

Comment: -filter would be faster if you could narrow down what you're looking for like *.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` is known to be slow to traverse directories recursively but it is what is built-in to PowerShell, it's a very handy and easy to use cmdlet. If you're looking for speed and efficiency you may need to default to .NET API calls to [`IO.Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=net-6.0).

Haven't tested this enough but I believe it should be working, as in, **finding any directory that is empty and is older than 90 days in this case**.

Worth noting that this code **requires .NET Framework 4+** if running Windows PowerShell.

```sh
$queue = [Collections.Generic.Queue[IO.DirectoryInfo]]::new()
$olderThan = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-90)         # => Set limit date here!
$queue.Enqueue('F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound') # => Starting path here!

while($queue.Count) {
    $dir = $queue.Dequeue()
    try {
        $isEmpty = $true
        foreach ($i in $dir.EnumerateDirectories()) {
            if($i.Attributes -band [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint) {
                # skip if it is ReparsePoint
                continue
            }
            $isEmpty = $false
            $queue.Enqueue($i)
        }

        if($isEmpty -and $dir.CreationTime -lt $olderThan -and -not $dir.EnumerateFiles().GetEnumerator().MoveNext()) {
            # output the directory if the 3 conditions are `$true`, no folders or files and older than
            $dir
        }
    }
    catch {
        # if we were unable to enumerate this directory, go next
        continue
    }
}
```

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`DirectoryInfo` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0)
- [`EnumerateDirectories()` instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratedirectories?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-enumeratedirectories)
- [`EnumerateFiles()` instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-enumeratefiles)
- [`Queue<T>` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-6.0)
- [`FileAttributes` Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it makes sense and I can follow the example. I would like to know where is the definite source of documentation on how to use .Net in powershell, i.e. where to find the info on [Collections.Generic.Queue[IO.DirectoryInfo]], [IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint, etc?

Comment: @puravidaso I added the relevant documentation from the .NET MS Docs. There is no documentation that I can think of that teaches how to make .NET API calls on PowerShell (in a general way)

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72193515/45375):

In addition to the implementation inefficiency you have discovered, there is another reason [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) is slow: it decorates each [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) / [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) output object with instance-level [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) properties - see [GitHub issue #7501](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7501), which explains the problem and suggests a streamlined class-level solution.

Using .NET APIs directly is indeed needed to work around the performance problems - a general caveat is that **you should always use *full* paths when calling .NET methods, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's**.

The fast equivalent of:

```bash
Get-ChildItem F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound -Recurse -Directory | % { $_.fullname }
```

is the following, which uses the [`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories) method:

```bash
[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories(
  'F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound', 
  '*', 
  'AllDirectories'  # Equivalent of -Recurse, a [System.IO.SearchOption] enum value
)
```

**Caveats**:

- Inaccessible directories:

  - In *Windows PowerShell* / .NET Framework they invariably cause an exception that aborts the enumeration.
  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* / .NET you now have the option to ignore inaccessible directories, via a new method overload that accepts a [`[System.IO.EnumerationOptions]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions) instance.
- Symlinks / reparse points:

  - In *Windows PowerShell* / .NET Framework they are *invariably followed* (including by `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`).
  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* / .NET you now have to option to opt-out (and `Get-ChildItem` now requires opt-*in* via `-FollowSymlink`)

---

The [`[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) class too has a `.EnumerateDirectories()` method, albeit as an *instance* method; the major difference is that `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instances rather than path *strings* are returned:

```bash
([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] 'F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound').EnumerateDirectories(
  '*', 
  'AllDirectories'
)
```

You can leverage the above to perform the desired filtering - finding only empty directories that are older than N days - with a minimum of PowerShell code:

```bash
$cutOffDate = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-30) # adjust as needed.
([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] 'F:\logs\PRV_RequestLogs\inbound').EnumerateDirectories(
  '*', 
  'AllDirectories'
) | Where-Object { 
      $_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutOffDate -and  
      0 -eq ($_.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() | Select-Object -First 1).Count
    }
```

Note the use of the [`.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos) method to enumerate all files and subdirectories, followed by selecting - at most - one via [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) `-First 1`, which stops the enumeration as soon as one item has been enumerated. A `.Count` value of `0` implies that the directory at hand is empty.

Comment: The big issue are exceptions stopping the enumeration, one of many reasons to love .NET Core and to dislike Framework hehe

Comment: Yeah, @Santiagio - these APIs didn't grow up until .NET Core 2.1 came around.